# Web Scrapping R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Tentei diversas maneiras mas não consigo fazer o scrapping da seguinte tabela:

http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/TxRef1.asp.

Até o momento através do seguine código:

```
   library("rvest")

URL <-'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/TxRef1.asp'
    
    
    bfm.tx <- URL %>%
      xml2::read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="tb_principal1"]') %>%
      html_table()
    tx.df <- bfm.tx [[1]]
```

Porém não é retornada nenhuma informação. Tentei usar o excel , porém o botão chama uma função dentro do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente selecionar usando: `html_node('.tabConteudo')`

```
library(rvest) 
url <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/TxRef1.asp'
pagina <- read_html(url)
pagina

a <- pagina %>% 
  html_node('.tabConteudo') %>%
  html_nodes('td') %>%
  html_text()

library(stringr)

a <- a[5:length(a)]

b <- str_split(a, '"',simplify = T)
b <- matrix(b, ncol = 3, byrow = T )
```

Deve ter uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso mas em resumo eu filtrei usando `html_nodes`, depois removi os cabeçalhos  `a[5:length(a)]`, depois converti em uma matrix `str_split(a, '"',simplify = T)`, e logo após defini as dimensões da matrix  `matrix(b, ncol = 3, byrow = T )` . Creio que você possa transformar em um data.frame e trabalhar de maneira mais eficiente.